# why I can not find out the data which insert in influxdb within 5 hours

Tags: python, influxdb

I have a script for test my influxdb:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import time
now_time = "2016-03-21 15:03:46"
#now_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%XZ",time.localtime())
json_body = [
{
"measurement": "info_cpu_load3",
"tags":{
"host": "1",
"cpu": "cpu0"
},
"time": "%s"%time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X",time.localtime()),
"fields": {
"user":12,
"iowait":15
}
}
]
client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'monitor')

client.create_database('monitor')

client.write_points(json_body)
```

when i comment the line "now_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%XZ",time.localtime())" it will works fine,but uncomment this line,I can't find anything from the databases,why?

Comment: How are you trying to query the data? Can you give us the exact query?

Comment: thks.I have solved the problem，it cause of the time zone,my system use the CST time zone,so the database and real time difference of 8 hour

Comment: You should write that up as an answer and accept it then. Glad you fixed it. :)

Comment: year,thks for your answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it cause of the time zone,after searching around the influxdb documentation,I get that influxdb only support utc time,so I solution that question by write a function for transform local time to utc time.

```
import pytz
def utctime(self,times):
        '''
        transform local time to utc time
        :param times:
        :return:
        '''
        try:
            utc = pytz.utc
            cmd = "cat /etc/sysconfig/clock|cut -d = -f 2"
            out,err,stat = exec_shell(cmd)
            now_utc = out.read().strip()
            fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            amsterdam = pytz.timezone(now_utc)
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(times, fmt)
            am_dt = amsterdam.localize(dt)
            utc_time = am_dt.astimezone(utc).strftime(fmt)
        except Exception,err:
            utc_time = 1
            dlog("utctime err:%s"%err)
        return utc_time
```